# Isomorphism of quotients over isomorphic commutators

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Given two (finite) groups $G$ and $D$ and their commutators $G'$ and $D'$, is it true that if $G/(G') \cong D/(D') $ and $G' \cong D'$, then $G \cong D$?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $G=D_8$ and $D=Q_8$. Here $G'\cong D' \cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $G/G' \cong D/D' \cong V_4$, where $V_4$ is the Klein four-group.